# Hide completed list items in Google Keep

Tags: google-keep

I have several Google Keep notes that work as a to-do list. (One for groceries, one for work things, and one for my private life things.)

But it kind of annoys me that completed tasks (list items) stay in my view until I delete them. It would be nicer if they disappeared when I mark them as completed (as in Google Tasks).

A solution would be to give every bullet point its own note but I think this blows everything a bit up.

Answer (score 10):

This seems to be relatively new behavior, but now when you "check" an item, it is segregated to the bottom of the note in a separate area marked "Checked".

[image: check list]

Even better, if you click the down arrow next to "Checked", it'll "close" the whole section.

[image: check list, with "Checked" closed]

You can control this behavior of checked items (staying with the list or moving to the bottom) by opening the settings menu and checking "move checked items to the bottom".

Comment: Does this still happen? I remember it used to work, but now I can't seen to make it do it. Didn't know if it was just me or not?

Comment: @WORMSS: It does still work. The settings have changed location a bit. They're now in the hamburger menu.

Comment: @AI E. Thank you.. Found them in settings.

Comment: This is great. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Keep now has a "Delete checked items" action

[image: delete checked items]

Comment: I dont see this button. Was this removed?

Comment: Never mind. Its available on PC - wish this was available on the mobile app too

Answer (score 0):

Keep moved this setting from a list-specific settings to the global settings, which can be found in the menu bar at the keep homepage. If you check this option then the checked items in a list will automatically be moved to the "Completed items" section as [Ale](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/354/ale) wrote in [his answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/67689/173883)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

an indirect answer to the original question, but you might consider using "Google Tasks" for "To-do-lists"... https://support.google.com/tasks/answer/7675772?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop